# Bash: execute a command with quotes and put its output into a variable

Tags: bash

In a bash script I set a command this way:

```
getdblist_cmd=(sudo -u $backup_user $psql -p $pgsql_port -U $pgsql_user -d postgres -q -t -c 'SELECT datname from pg_database')
```

Then I run it with

```
dblist=`${getdblist_cmd[@]}`
```

I don't get any error into the bash script but the `$dblist` variable is empty.

How can I execute that command and put its output into a variable?

Comment: What does `"${getdblist_cmd[@]}"` by itself do, without the command substitution or assignment?

Comment: This really looks like a job for a shell function, not an array.

Comment: It puts the command into the variable without executing it

Comment: It's not clear what the array is buying you in this case.  Could you try to simplify a bit.  That is, `getdblist_cmd="sudo -u..."` and then `dblist=$($getdblist_cmd)` ?  I also replaced your backtics with `$()` - which is now preferred.

Comment: With `getdblist_cmd="sudo -u postgres $psql -p $pgsql_port -U $pgsql_user -d postgres -q -t -c 'SELECT datname from pg_database'"` it works and get output but quotes are not used correctly, because I'm getting `ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'SELECT"
LINE 1: 'SELECT
        ^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dblist=`"${getdblist_cmd[@]}"`
        ^                   ^
```

The `[@]` operator works only correct if the `${...}` is surrounded by quotes.